# verify two lists of lists at specific indexes

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists of lists. They are unequal. Depending on the data, sometimes first list is longer, sometimes second list is longer or they might be the same size.

```
L1 = [['X00010', '9654123', 4.1, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 90.01], \
      ['X00011', '2021230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001], \
      ['X00012', '2021230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001], \
      ['X00013', '9654173', 4.11, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 90.01], \
      ['X00014', '7754173', 4.11, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 90.01]]
L2 = [['X00020', '2021230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00002], \
      ['X00021', '2221230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001], \
      ['X00022', '2021230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001]]
```

I need to iterate through each sublist and and see if each sublist matches elements at index:2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and then pull the sublists that match in a new list SAME = [] and the ones that do not match any other sublist from the other list in DIFFERENT =[]

First of all I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to loop for each element in first list against second list.

If I use a zip(L1, L2) will just pair two by two, and obvious will leave out all elements that are in the longer list.

If I use `map(None, L1, L2)` , I can zip based on longest, but still I end up with pair index<->index and did not check all lists from first against each from second list.

I could not find a clear explanation in the Python Cookbook. Maybe I'm missing something?

I'm stuck with Python 2.7 on this solution.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the expected output for the example provided?

Comment: @ Scott Hunter here is one of the pulls I want. Thank you!. SAME = [['X00011', '2021230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001], \ # because has the same values as X00021 and X00022 at indices 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 ['X00012', '2021230', 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001]] \ # because has the same values as X00021 and X00022 at indices 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches your description, as best I understand it:

```
SAME = []
DIFF = []

for x1 in L1:
    DIFF.append( x1 ) # Assume it is different
    for x2 in L2:
        if x1[2:9] == x2[2:9]:
            SAME.append( DIFF.pop() )  # Move it from DIFF to SAME
            break
```